Can sqlx be used with Apache Doris?
When trying to connect to an Apache Doris using rusts sqlx with tokio, I receive the following error message:
Database(MySqlDatabaseError { code: Some("HY000"), number: 1105, message: "errCode = 2, detailMessage = Set statement does't support non-constant expr." })

It seems that sqlx uses some SET command when connecting. Is there a way to work around this?
I also tried using the mysql_async crate, which failed with this message
Server(ServerError { code: 1193, message: "errCode = 2, detailMessage = Unknown system variable 'socket'", state: "HY000" })

The mysql crate works, but some an async crate is what I need.
